# NameError in HomeOrdersController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am a beginner in programming in ruby on rails and I have this problem:

```
NameError in HomeOrdersController#new
uninitialized constant HomeOrdersController::HomeOrder

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

  def new
    @home_order = HomeOrder.new
  end

  def edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a model called HomeOrder?

Try:

rails g model HomeOrder

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner, let me explain the problem for you!

---

**Model**

The error you have is that you're trying to call an undefined constant (`Model`), which Rails cannot find. As Rails is built on Ruby, it expects your `Model` to be pre-loaded, and able to be called from your controller

You'll basically need to fix the error by creating a model & corresponding database. There are two ways to do this - manual & automatic:

-

**Manual**

```
#app/models/home_order.rb
class HomeOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

> $ rails g migration CreateHomeOrders

```
#db/migrate/create_home_orders.rb
class CreateHomeOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table(:home_orders) do |t|
        t.column :name, :string, limit: 60
        # Other fields here
      end 
   end
end
```

> $ rails db:migrate

-

**Automatic**

You'll be able to create a model automatically using the Rails model generator:

> $ rails g model HomeOrder

This will create the model file (stored in `app/models/home_order.rb`), as well as giving you a migration which you can then populate as I described above

You would then be able to run the following to push the migration:

> $ rake db:migrate

This should give you the ability to load the model you require